# Finding Occurrences of Cities with Origin Location and Destination Location using MySQL in a given table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

I am trying to solve this problem but I am not able to make much headway. I am stuck on how to list elements which are part of just origin location and not destination location and vice versa.

Table Name: Shipments

| Shipment_ID | Pickup Date | Delivery Date | Origin Location | Destination Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Jan 01 2020 | Feb 10 2020 | Detroit | Seattle |
| 102 | Jan 02 2020 | Jan 10 2020 | Seattle | Los Angeles |
| 103 | Jan 01 2020 | Feb 10 2020 | Los Angeles | New York City |
| 104 | Feb 10 2020 | Mar 14 2020 | New York City | New York City |
| 105 | Jan 03 2020 | Mar 11 2020 | Los Angeles | Seattle |
| 106 | Jan 02 2020 | Feb 10 2020 | Dallas | Portland |

Answer: FINAL SCHEMA

| Location | Total pickups | Total deliveries |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Detroit | 1 | 0 |
| Seattle | 1 | 2 |
| Los Angeles | 2 | 1 |
| New York City | 1 | 2 |
| Dallas | 1 | 0 |
| Portland | 0 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT towns.town Location,
       SUM(Shipments.origin = towns.town) pickups
       SUM(Shipments.destination = towns.town) deliveries
FROM ( SELECT origin town FROM Shipments
       UNION 
       SELECT destination town FROM Shipments ) towns
JOIN Shipments ON towns.town IN (Shipments.origin, Shipments.destination)
GROUP BY towns.town
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to do this as:

```
select location,
       sum(is_origin) as pickups,
       sum(is_destination) as deliveries
from ((select origin as location, 1 as is_origin, 0 as is_destination
       from shipments
      ) union all
      (select destination as location, 0 as is_origin, 1 as is_destination
       from shipments
      )
     ) od
group by location;
```

No additional `JOIN` is needed.